# Mass renaming files

Tags: linux

I've got 25,000 ++ images in a folder on server. Lots of them have %20 in them and that prevents them from displaying. Does anyone know how I could do a command line to str_replace('%20', '_', $imagename) ?

Thanks

Comment: Are they all in a single folder?

Comment: See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small python snippet can help you probably:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if "%20" in name:
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, name), os.path.join(root, name.replace("%20", "_")))
            print("renamed: %s" % name)
```

Note the "." argument to `os.walk`. Either change it to the path to the directory where files reside, or otherwise run the script from that directory.

Comment: thanks but I get an error at command line using exactly what you posted

Comment: I assumed you are on a UNIX-like machine, which maybe was my issue. You need to save it into a file, called something like `rename.py`, and run as `python rename.py`. Sorry.

Comment: ./rename.py line:1 import:command not found line:3 unexpected token 'dirs'

Comment: Not `./rename.py`, but `python rename.py`. If you want to run it as `./rename.py`, add `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line in the script.

Answer (score 3):

this might work http://snipplr.com/view/2736/

(code provided here for future reference)

```
for i in *.avi
do
  j=`echo $i | sed 's/find/replace/g'`
  mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

Can also be written on a single line as

```
for i in *.avi; do j=`echo $i | sed 's/find/replace/g'`; mv "$i" "$j"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is get a list of files in a file i.e. using 'ls -1 | awk '{print "mv $1 $1"}' > torename.sh', then editing the torename.sh using regular expressions. Once you've got the script to what you want, run the script.

Comment: I could do anything I want with php but am not too good at linux. Could you please post exact command line? Thanks